# Exporting Tensorflow model to Android

Tags: android, python, tensorflow, porting

I originally have a code for generating and training a CNN model, with no added codes for saving or writing graph.

However, the optimized .pb file I generated using this code is not accepted in Android Studio and emulation stops.

What I did are the following:

1. Using my basic code for generating the CNN model, I added these lines in the training portion:

[image]

2. I edited my input placeholder and my output prediction by adding the "name" attribute,

`X = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape [None,input_height,input_width,num_channels], name="input")`

`y_ = tf.nn.softmax(tf.matmul(f, out_weights) + out_biases, name='y_')`

because I think these are needed to create the graph. I did not add any other code to my original code other than this

3. Then after saving the model, after generating the .pbtxt and .ckpt file, you freeze the model and generate the .pb file

[image]

I put this block of code outside of

```
in with session as tf.Session():
```

after training.

4. Then you still need to optimize this .pb file

[image]

I put this block of code outside of

```
in with session as tf.Session():
```

after training.

The final optimized model that will be placed in the assets folder in my Android Studio Project will be `optimized_frozen_har.pb`

But the emulation stops. I'm using my phone. If I simulated using the original `optimized_frozen_har.pb` file there aren't any errors. And the file size of the original `optimized_frozen_har.pb` file is 21kB but the one I generated is just 4kB.

Maybe there is the problem with code for generating the frozen and optimized model. Aside from adding the "name" attribute for the input and the output, should I add other lines of code in my original code? (such as `with namescope..`, etc

Comment: Copy and paste your code, don't provide pictures of your code.

Comment: @Khristos i tried earlier but Stackoverflow is not accepting it

Comment: @Khristos I have already placed my entired code. The screenshots where from the tutorial that I was following.

Comment: I don't have android studio to test the code right now, I'll leave it to those more capable to answer.

Comment: Are you able to read the model with plain Java?